# Is there a way to use an existing function as a part of a class? If yes, how?

Tags: c++, function, class

I have a function that I want to use in different classes. Is this possible?

Example:

```
int getNumber()
{
  // do something here that will use some values like:
  int number = num * pi;
  return number;
}

class Human
{
  int num;
  // other member
  int getNumber(); // same as above
}

class Robot
{
  int num;
  // other member
  int getNumber(); // same as above
}
```

The `getNumber()` function can be short as `return num;` or long depends on the computation that will happen inside the function.

The `num` value inside the `getNumber()` is the `num` member of both `Human` and `Robot` class. Although, these classes do not have the parent-child or friend relationship.

Comment: Would a friend function do?

Comment: any reason why you cannot just call `getNumber()` passing `num` as a parameter and let `getNumber()` be independent function?

Comment: I didn't see any real usage of this proposal, could you please give me one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is certainly easy. Although there is no sweet syntax for delegation in C++ (a shame, this has brought so many abuses of inheritance...).

*1. The free-function way*

```
int transformNumber(int num) { return num * pi; }

class Human {
public:
    int getNumber() const { return transformNumber(num); }

private:
    int num;
};
```

*2. The composition way*

```
struct NumberThing {
    int num;

    int getNumber() { return num * pi; }
};

class Human {
public:
    int getNumber() { thing.getNumber(); }

private:
    NumberThing thing;
};
```

Pick your favorite.

Comment: +1 for suggesting delegation. This is almost certainly the correct answer.

Comment: Thank you. I am picking #1, since what I need is that the `num` can be any member of any class.

Answer (score 0):

Make a class that has this function and extend other classes that uses that functionality.

Answer (score -1):

This is a good instance to use inheritance. Both objects have stuff in common often mean that they are really subclasses of a more general class:

```
class Being
{
    int num;
    int getNumber() {/* .. */}
}

class Robot: public Being
{

}

class Human: public Being
{

}
```

Comment: Actually, it's a terrible usage of inheritance. Inheritance models a **is-a** relationship, using `class SpaceShip: public Being` just because `Being` has a `getNumber` function is silly. You could, reasonably, *encapsulate* a `Being` (by composition) within `Robot` and `Human`, though without delegation ... you would have to write a forwarder method.

Comment: But having common features is a strong indication that two classes has an is-a relationship to a higher class. If `class SpaceShip` also has a `getNumber` function then that indicates that `class Being` should be renamed as `class Thing` instead

Comment: no, features do not model a *is-a* relationship, behavior does. It might seem a fine line, but it's an essential concept.